# refactor async, await, fetch into angular http response

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an Angular 10 project and am wondering if this line of code below

`const xml = await fetch('/assets/' + path).then((response) => response.text());`

can be refactored into an angular HTTP request. Die XML variable is a string that I used later as an argument for another function. Since Angular HTTP Request returns an Observable, am I wrong to assume that what I want to achieve is impossible?

Comment: You can use the rxjs toPromise() function since the httpClient.get() function returns a observable. It should work as a native js promise.

Comment: @Havald: `toPromise` is [deprecated](https://indepth.dev/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated/) in RxJS 7 and will be gone in RxJS 8.

Comment: @MichaelD thanks for the information did not know about it being deprecated. Then i think the best way is to refactor the whole function in an rxjs way instead of one line.